# How to test Iterators (including the off-the-end and the before-the-beginning iterators) to a list or forward_list remain valid,

Tags: c++

Working through C++ Primer and puzzled by Exercise 9.25.

Consider the following code erasing all elements from a list:

```
list<int> lst = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
elem1 = lst.begin();
elem2 = lst.end();
elem1 = lst.erase(elem1, elem2);
```

Exercise 9.25 asks about invalid elements: what happens if elem2 or both elem1 and elem2 are the off-the-end iterator?

How do I write code to test this question that has an off-the-end iterator?

I have tried this:

```
std::list<int> lst = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
lst.erase(lst.begin(), ++lst.end());
```

According to the text at section 9.3.6.: The answer is

```
Iterators, pointers, and references (including the off-the-end and the 
before-the-beginning iterators) to a list or forward_list remain valid.
```

How do I create a sample code to see that the solution is correct? That iterators remain valid? When I use the above code the error thrown is  "list iterator not incrementable"

Comment: I edited the question. Since the answer is "Iterators, pointers, and references (including the off-the-end and the before-the-beginning iterators) to a list or forward_list remain valid." How do I create a off-the-end iterator to test list.erase?

Comment: note that you can't increment `lst.end()`, that's the "one-past-the-end" iterator. (Well you can, but it makes your program ill-formed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism to check if an iterator, pointer or reference is valid. In some cases, if you know an iterator or pointer will become invalidated, you can set it to a known value such as `nullptr` (for pointers) or the containers `end` iterator (for iterators). Usually, you must simply design your software in such a way that you never preform an operation on an invalidated iterator. Once an iterator is invalidated it cannot be used, even to compare it with other iterators to see if it's valid.

If you want to check if a valid iterator is a past-the-end iterator, you would usually compare it with the container's `end` iterator (see [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)).